# How to get the encrypted P parameter in Outbound E-mail templates

Tags: outbound-email

We have a requirement to send an e-mail to a specific group from Outbound E-mail to upgrade their account by visiting a special page.

When people click on the link in the e-mail, they should be presented with a page with their personal details.

Is there a way to include just the encrypted P parameter in this custom link in the Outbound E-mail Page Template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A coworker found a workaround for this problem. Without some official placeholder to be replaced with the P parameter, the only way to work around this problem is to empty one of the URL fields in the Audience Management tab in the Publication properties.

When you use the corresponding placeholder in your template, Outbound E-mail will replace the placeholder with something similar to "?p=AAA12345". For example, putting

```
http://abc.net[__ChangeProfileUrl__]
```

in your template will end up as

```
http://abc.net?p=AAA12345
```

in the resulting e-mail, assuming you emptied the "Change profile page URL" in the publication properties. In this manner you could place the P parameter at the end of about any URL in your templates.

Answer (score 2):

The P parameter is automatically generated by the Outbound Email API. I can imagine a way to only get the P parameter.

- In your Page / Component Template add a DWT template that will be the first TBB executed in the pipeline. This TBB content will be

  @@OutboundEmail_ConfirmURL@@
- As a second TBB in your pipeline add a second .NET TBB that will read the Output Package Item that will in this case contain the confirmation URL including the P parameter. This TBB will need to only get the P parameter, may be using a Regular Expression and then create another Package Item that will contain the P parameter
- Use the Package Item in your subsequent TBBs to build the Custom Link
- In the CD use the Contact API to retrieve a Content from the P paramenter

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure this will work. The p parameter isn't filled in until the actual e-mail is being sent by the mailing processor from Outbound E-mail. The p parameter is different for each e-mail being sent out, because it contains the Contact ID + Source ID and probably more. I was hoping for some placeholder like [*__ChangeProfileUrl__*] for the P parameter.

Answer (score 2):

If you make the link tracked (e.g. using `@@GetLinkTrackingURL(componentUriOrHref)@@`), it will include the "p" parameter and you can use it to log in as that Contact.

There's no public API method to generate the "p" parameter, but even if there was you wouldn't be able to do it in your templates; it's specific to an individual e-mail, which will only be created later by the Mailer Service.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the case.